# loop three digit numbers where product == sum

Tags: javascript

So I have this task where I have to nest three loops together then find out all the three digit numbers where product == sum.

For example:

```
123

1*2*3 = 6
1+2+3 = 6
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
var summen = a + b + c;
var produktet = a * b * c;

for (var i = 100; i <= 100; i++) {
for (var j = 100; j <= 101; j++) {
    for (var e = 100; e < 1000; e++) {
            if (summen == produktet) {
                pOutput.innerHTML += e + " ";

     }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance and any help is really appreciated!

(i thought that i need to use if and else but i'm basically stuck to be honest)

Comment: `I have to nest three loops together` it can be done without nesting three loops

Comment: Not to spoil anything, but it's really only 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321 ;-)

Comment: @brk - yeah i know but honestly i think my teacher only wants it to be harder or something...

Comment: @LucaKiebel yeah ikr--- but they made this task for us dammit

Comment: How have you tried to solve the problem so far? Questions asking for _homework help_ must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @LucaKiebel hi, i edited my post and added how far ive come. as u can see i understand the basic of it . sighs but i know the part is wrong because the number is not splitted up as a, b and c

Comment: Why are you starting the loop at 100 and end it right there? here, the sum and  product will never be equal, because a,b and c don't hold any value at all.

Comment: @LucaKiebel i'm staring the loop at 100 because that's where the three digit numbers start? And yeah I figured that out, so I wonder how should I do it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with three loops, use three that start at 0 and end at 9, and then add and multiply in the inner loop:

```js
let output = [];

for (let a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
  for (let b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
      if (a * b * c === a + b + c) output.push("" + a + b + c)
    }
  }
}

console.log(output)
```

Comment: this one worked super well. thank you so much!! it was easy to understand with all the loops.

Comment: I'm really new to this community, but I've learnt a lot so far. So I wonder if I'm right at this point. the [ ] tells me that it's an array right? and the push part adds it back to the array or?

Comment: Correct, `push` adds an item to the end of the array

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate from zero to `999` and take the stringed value as array. Then check the sum against the product and store the value if equal.

```js
const
    sum = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b),
    product = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a * b);

var i,
    temp,
    values = [];
    
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    temp = Array.from(i.toString().padStart(3, '0'), Number);
    if (sum(temp) === product(temp)) {
        values.push(temp.join(''));
    }
}
console.log(values);
```

Comment: this worked- but i still haven't learned array yet so i feel like using this i won't understand anything aha. once i've learned array i will look back at this to understand it but thank you!